# Get rows in one table that are not in other based on two columns in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in two tables as below.
--Table1

| Col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 9 | 10 |

--Table2

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 11 | 12 |

I need to fetch only the rows in table1 that dont exist in table2
i.e.
i need to filter out the data where

1. both col1 and col2 have matching data in both tables
2. either col1 or col2 has matching data in both tables

and fetch only the remaining rows. In the data set shown here i should be fetching only the following row. Need to fatch only the values 9 and 10 that are present in table1 and not in table2
How can i achieve this oracle sql?

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 10 |

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest something like this, faster than the "not exists" which runs subqueries - can be costly with large tables:

```
select t1.*
  from table1 t1 
  left join table2 t2 
    on t1.col1 = t2.col1 or t1.col2 = t2.col2
 where t2.col1 is null
```

HTH

Comment: I''m not an Oracle guy, but https://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/ is perhaps worth reading.

Comment: Please clarify why do you think that `left join` would be faster than `not exists`

Comment: many thanks , The tables i am working with has roughly 40 and 90million rows. The query was running for a long time. is there a way to optimize it further to deal with the data of this size.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select * from t2
                  where t2.c1 = t1.c1
                     or t2.c2 = t1.c2)
```

Comment: many thanks , The tables i am working with has roughly 40 and 90million rows. The query  was running for a long time. is there a way to optimize it further to deal with the data of this size.

Comment: I'd ask a new question, with table and index definitions, and explain plans.

Comment: Hi , i dont have control on the source tables as they are managed by different applications. so i cant create indices . however, i have attached the explain plan

Comment: If you can't create any indexes. there's nothing you can do to improve the performance - afaik,